# How to tell if Folder is opened in explorer

Tags: vb.net, directory, window, explorer

I'm writing a script in Siemens NX using vb.net, which helps export drawing files. The file will be exported into a folder, that is kind of bothersome to manually navigate to, so I want to open said folder up to the user after the export.

The target folder is in a plm safe, so the file needs to be checked in in order to be used by other people.

`Process.Start(targetfolder)` doesn't work, because the folder gets opened "dumb" without any of the plm safe functionality.

`Process.Start("explorer.exe", targetfolder)` opens the folder using the proper safe environment, however it will open a second folder when I run it again. Ideally I would like the folder to only become active if it's already opened.

I found that I could use

```
<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
    Private Function FindWindow(ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As IntPtr
    End Function
```

...

```
If FindWindow(vbNullString, IO.Path.GetFileName(targetfolder)) = 0 Then
            Process.Start("explorer.exe", targetfolder)
        Else
            AppActivate(IO.Path.GetFileName(targetfolder))
        End If
```

In order to only open a new window if there isn't one already. However, this also doesn't work reliably, because `IO.Path.GetFileName(targetfolder)` returns only the folder's name without the entire path. This means that if the user has a folder opened, that has the same name as the target folder but sits in a different spot `FindWindow(vbNullString, IO.Path.GetFileName(targetfolder))` will find the other folder to be opened and won't open the target folder. It essentially can't differentiate the two. Additionally, `AppActivate(IO.Path.GetFileName(targetfolder))` doesn't work if there are two folders of the same name opened.

Another thing I found was that you cannot rename a directory using `FileSystem.Rename()` while a child folder of the target folder is opened. I could use this to check if the target folder is opened, by trying to rename the parent folder, however this will create many many false positives.

I am now officially out of ideas. I also cannot use the plm safe's API, because the NX-script doesn't allow the use of "foreign" dll files, such as the plm library.

How do I check if a specific path is already opened in an explorer window?

Comment: Process.Start returns the Process that was started, and that has a unique ID. You could store that ID, and then check later if that process id was still active maybe?

Comment: @Slugsie unfortunately, I can't really store stuff as it's a macro and all objects that are created by it will be destroyed when it's finished. They will not persist until the macro is run again.

Comment: Using UI Automation or Win32 functions calls, you can get the inner `ToolbarWindow32` control of the `Breadcrumb Parent` container. The `Name` (UI Automation) of `Text` (Win32) is the full path of the folder currently shown. -- You can also use Shell interfaces to get there, but it's probably more *complicated* in this context.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8520949/11465149), you could do something along those lines:

```vb
Private Function isPathOpenedInExplorer(myPath As String) As Boolean
    Dim shellWindows As SHDocVw.ShellWindows = New SHDocVw.ShellWindows()
    Dim filename As String

    For Each ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer In shellWindows
        filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(ie.FullName).ToLower()
        If filename.Equals("explorer") Then
            If myPath = ie.LocationURL.Remove(0, 8).Replace("/", "\").Replace("%20", " ") Then
                Return True ' Found
            End If
        End If
    Next

    Return False 'Not Found
End Function
```

don't forget to `Imports System.IO` and [Add reference to 'SHDocVw'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20845383/11465149)